# two div with position relative behind (overlapping)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

tl;dr: First div with `position: relative` is above second div with `position: relative`. They must be overlapping.

I have a carousel in bootstrap. I want change slider effect (from right to left) to smooth  transition opacity 0-1 (when the first div disappears the other one is showing in the same place).

So to do this every div's must have the same `width`/`height`/`top`/`left` parametr.
`.active` item must be identical like `.active .left` and `.next .left`. My first idea was to create sth like this:

```
.active, .carousel-inner>.item.next.left, .carousel-inner>.item.prev.right
```

and give exacly the same parametrs + `position: relative`.

Here is the problem. First div with `position: relative` is above second div with `position: relative`. This makes the effect a smooth transition does't work.

[image: overlapping div's with position relative]

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

`margin-top` in second div must be exactly the same like height of first div (for example `margin-top: -50%`)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be dynamic instead of manually programming in the height/margin, give the first div `position: absolute`. That will cause the other elements to disregard it and the second `div` will be right on top of it.

https://jsfiddle.net/dk9gwnkj/2/